# Lemma from arithmetic functions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ arithmetic and $$H(f)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x\log x}\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)\log n,$$
Then $H(f)$ exists if and only if $M(f)$ exists, and $M(f)=H(f)$ Where $$M(f)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{1\over x}\sum_{n\leq x}f(n).$$

I don't know if I have to use the fact that $$M(f)\implies L(f)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{1\over \log(x)}\sum_{n\leq x}{f(n)\over n}.$$

Comment: Same question was answered before. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68966/mean-value-of-arithmetic-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$ M_{x} = \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \leq x} f(n) \quad \text{and} \quad H_{x} = \frac{1}{x \log x} \sum_{n \leq x} f(n) \log n. $$

As suggested by i707107,s comment, we can use a similar argument to show that

\begin{align*}
H_{x}
&= \frac{1}{x\log x} \int_{1^{-}}^{x} f(t) \log t \, d[t]
 = \frac{1}{x\log x} \int_{1^{-}}^{x} \log t \, d ( t M_{t} ) \\
&= \frac{1}{x \log x} \left[ \log t \cdot t M_{t} \right]_{1^{-}}^{x} - \frac{1}{x \log x} \int_{1}^{x} M_{t} \, dt \\
&= M_{x} - \frac{1}{x \log x} \int_{1}^{x} M_{t} \, dt.
\end{align*}

Since $M_{x} \to M(f)$ as $x \to \infty$, we have

$$ \int_{1}^{x} M_{t} \, dt = O(x) $$

and it follows that $H_{x} \to M(f)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't know why we can say that $$\frac{1}{x\log x}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{x}f(t)\log t d[t]=\frac{1}{x\log x}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{x}\log t d(t M_t).$$

Comment: @Elmogoya, both $f(t) \, d[t]$ and $d (t M_{t})$ are (real-valued) measures on $\Bbb{N}_{1} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots \}$ such that for each $t = n \in \Bbb{N}_{1}$ the mass density is given by $f(n)$. That's why they are the same.